# IHostedService Manager C# .net6

Tags: c#, .net, ihostedservice

I have a .NET 6 project with a large number of classes that inherit from IHostedService. All of them receive two input parameters: Config config and LogManager logManager. Are there any ready-made TaskManagers for managing these tasks, such as starting, stopping, and restarting them with new input data (config)?

I have tried searching on GitHub and on the internet, and I can even write it myself, but is there at least a template for customization provided?

Comment: I saw Nick Chapsas do a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA_3CZmD9y0&t=476s&ab_channel=NickChapsas) about it, its not exactly what you need and also .Net 8 but it can give you some direction

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please go read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example, then edit your question